# Solr stop words replaced with _ symbol

Tags: solr, solrj, stop-words, spring-data-solr

I have problems with solr stopwords in my autosuggest. All stopwords was replaced by _ symbol.

For example I have text "the simple text in" in field "deal_title". When I try to search word "simple" solr show me next result "_ simple text _" but I expect "simple text".

Could someone explain me why this works in such way and how to fix it ?
Here is part of my schema.xml

```
<fieldType class="solr.TextField" name="text_auto">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory"/>
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/> 
        <filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" maxShingleSize="3" outputUnigrams="true" outputUnigramsIfNoShingles="false" /> 
    </analyzer> 
    <analyzer type="query">
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/> 
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/> 
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>

<field name="deal_title" type="text_auto" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="false"/>

<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="false"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="false"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Answer (score 2):

My solution to this in Solr 6.3 (where `enablePositionIncrements="false"` isn't possible anymore) was to:

1. remove stopwords
2. shingle with `fillerToken=""` (which removes the `_`)
3. remove leading and trailing spaced
4. remove duplicates

   ```
   <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" format="snowball" words="lang/stopwords_de.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
   <filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" fillerToken=""/>
   <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="(^ | $)" replacement=""/>
   <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
   ```

Comment: This is not correct because the RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory does not remove tokens with different position.
https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/filter-descriptions.html#FilterDescriptions-RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilter

Comment: This worked for me in Solr 7.6, though I did add an additional `PatternReplaceFilterFactory` to remove double spaces

Answer (score 0):

To fix this you need to use`<filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true" enablePositionIncrements="false" />`and `<luceneMatchVersion>4.3</luceneMatchVersion>` in solconfig.xml

Comment: I am using last solr version that's why I have <luceneMatchVersion>4.10.3</luceneMatchVersion> in my solconfig.xml. Looks like I should downgrade luceneMatchVersion because it doesn't work with current(4.10.3) version.

Comment: It doesn't work from Solr 4.4 and up. In Solr5 it will be removed. I'm trying to prevent that.

Comment: Also I have one more field with type "text_general" (described above) for searching(wildcard) using regex ""/.*"+phrase+".*/"" and it works well but stopwords doesn't work for this field(I think it's because solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory). Could you suggest some other filter ?

Comment: You mean stopwords was totally removed starting from version 4.4. ? And there are no any way to implement them in Solr version 4.10.3 without downgrading luceneMatchVersion ?