# solr stemming, stop words and shingles not giving expected outputs

Tags: solr, lucene

I am trying to remove the unwanted words and use stemming and finally create shingles. However, after removing stop words, its giving me shingles with "_" in the place of stop words. 
   I tried using PatternReplaceFactory to replace _ but its not working. I have field type as below:

```
<fieldType name="common_shingle" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer type="index">
          <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory"/>
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern=".*_.*" replacement=""/>
        <filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" outputUnigrams="false" minShingleSize="3" maxShingleSize="3"/>            
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

And when I analyse "A brown fox quickly jumps over the lazy dog". It gives me following result:

1. _ brown fox
2. brown fox quickli
3. fox quickli jump
4. quickli jump _
5. jump _ _
6. _ _ lazi
7. _ lazi dog

How do I remove _ from the shingle token. Also, is there a way to create shingles only from stop words?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28459949/solr-stop-words-replaced-with-symbol as well

Answer (score 1):

Thats because of stopwords
Set PositionIncrements to False and luceneMatchVersion to 4.3

Replace your StopFilterFactory with this.

```
  <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" luceneMatchVersion="4.3" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="false"/>
```

Comment: `luceneMatchVersion` as a filter parameter doesn't exist anymore as of solr 6. you'd have to set `<luceneMatchVersion>4.3</luceneMatchVersion>` in solconfig.xml.

Answer (score 1):

In the SOLR's Jira there is an improvement request with an available patch: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-11604

Compile a new lucene-analyzers-common.jar with this patch and use the skipFillerTokens="true" option in your schema.xml

```
<filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" ... skipFillerTokens="true"/>
```

If you want this patch to be included in the next SOLR version, vote for this Jira issue.

Answer (score 0):

The `_` is inserted by the ShingleFilter, as it replaces empty position increments with the token `_`.

If you want to remove the value, you'll have to perform the PatternReplace *after* the ShingleFilter, as it doesn't exist in the token stream before that.

ElasticSearch exposes an option to select the replacement character as "fillter_token", but Solr's implementation seem to directly use the Lucene implementation, so you should be able to use `fillerToken` to set this yourself. Try doing `fillerToken=""` in your ShingleFilter definition, instead of using the patternreplacefilter.

Comment: it is working. But, i want the exact 3 words shingles after the stop words being removed. Like as below:"
brown fox quickli,
fox quickli jump.
quickli jump lazi, jump lazi dog".    I don't want the space or _ in shingles

Comment: @SanjayLama OK - then that's what you should have asked :-) If you keep a magic filler token (such as `_`) in your text, you can move the PatternReplace to after the ShingleFilter and replace all tokens that contains `_` with "" (which is what your filter does), in effect removing them from the value of the field.

Comment: Its working like you said. However, it is skipping the works that contain stop words. Currently, its giving me only 2 shingles: 'brown fox quickli' and 'fox quickli jump'. Rest are just removed. I want the shingles to be formed after the stop words are been removed. Like as below:" brown fox quickli, fox quickli jump. quickli jump lazi, jump lazi dog" . If you could guide me through this it would really be helpful to me . Thank You.